# I'm developing PHP but my browser insists I download the file?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a PHP file which includes HTML, but for some reason when I navigate to this in the latest version of Chromium for Ubuntu 12.10 it tries to get me to download the file.

Does anyone know how I can change this?

Thank you.

Comment: What file does it want you to download? Your own php code?

Comment: @itsols PHP code cannot be downloaded

Comment: Are you using a web server like Apache with PHP installed?

Comment: Most likely you haven't set PHP up properly - if PHP isn't parsing the file, Chrome will get you to download it, and the contents of the file will include the PHP. Make sure you are using Apache, and that PHP is installed. Ensure you've restarted Apache as well to get it running.

Comment: don't run directly from your directory,keep your .php file in www directly and you must be install apache and php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't open `file://`, but `http://localhost`.

Did you start server?

Comment: Oh goodness. I forgot to put it in www to access it over localhost! Thanks all, I literally completely forgot to do this!

+1